# Particular solution of a non-homogenous partial differential equation.

Tags: differential-equations

$$ax^2\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}+bx\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+c\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}=10x^2+9x+6$$
where $a,b,c$ are constants,

initial conditions: $v(x,0)=0,v(0,y)=0$

i tried separation method but can't get particular solution

Comment: Separation should work. Is this homework?

Comment: no,this is not homework

Comment: The question to begin here would be perhaps for which values of $a$, $b$, $c\ $ a solution exists. For example, if $a=b=0\ $ then $u(x,y)=5x^2y^2/c + 3xy^2/c + 9 y^2/(2c) + C_2(x) y + C_1(x)\ $ and $u(0,y)=\frac{9 y^2}{2 c}+ C_2(0) y + C_1(0)\ $, so constants $C_1(0)$, $C_2(0)$ cannot be choosen to get $u(0,y)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A particular solution of the pde (obtained with Maple's help) is
$v(x,y) = \frac{5 x^2}{a+b} + \frac{9x}{b} + \frac{6 \ln x}{a-b}$.

Comment: Or, if you don't want a singularity at $x=0$, $\frac{5x^2}{a+b} + \frac{9x}{b} + \frac{3y^2}{c}$.

Comment: thanks man, i had tried mathematica without success but not maple ,but how you get second solution,means how we can exclude singularity while giving initial conditions/etc on maple?

Comment: but second solution doesn't fullfill initial conditions 

Comment: Typically, when solving a nonhomogeneous boundary value problem, you take a particular solution $v_p$ of the pde (without regard to boundary conditions), and then look for a solution $v_h$ of the homogeneous pde such that $v = v_h + v_p$ satisfies the boundary conditions.  Thus in your case, taking $v_p(x,y) = \frac{5x^2}{a+b} + \frac{9x}{b} + \frac{3y^2}{c}$, the boundary conditions for $v_h$ would be $v_h(x,0) = - v_p(x,0) = - \frac{5x^2}{a+b} - \frac{9x}{b}$
and $v_h(0,y) = -v_p(0,y) = - \frac{3y^2}{c}$. 

Comment: However, you're likely to have trouble with your problem because the pde is singular at $x=0$.  